# Ubuntu SSH 23.10 SSH issue (50-cloud-init.conf)?

Tags: server, ssh, 23.10, sshd

I just installed Ubuntu server 23.10 yesterday. I downloaded the iso directly from ubuntu.com. Everything went fine during the install. For security reasons, I always disable password authentication, so in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I set `PasswordAuthentication` to `no`. It wasn't working.

Well, I finally figured out why today. Apparently, during the installation, the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config/50-cloud-init.conf` was created and, in that file, there was a single line:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I've never had this issue before, but this is the first time I've used 23.10. The only difference during this installation is that I used the "minimal install". I don't know if that made a difference.

What is that file and why was it created? Is this a recent change? Apparently it was overwriting what was in `sshd_config`. I'm not sure if the way I fixed it was correct (but it worked). I just changed that value in that file to be `no` too.

Comment: @user68186 yep on physical hardware. The name of the iso i downloaded was `ubuntu-23.10-live-server-amd64`. I downloaded from the main ubuntu server download page.

Comment: What is the problem? You appear to have already discovered the solution in your question

Comment: From the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298550/changing-default-values-in-etc-ssh-sshd-config-using-cloud-init-config) to **Changing default values in /etc/ssh/sshd_config using cloud init config**: "Since Ubuntu 20.04, the default /etc/ssh/sshd_config ships with a new Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf directive precisely to solve your initial problem and to spare us of tricky (and error-prone) text manipulation using sed and friends, as creating a new file with just the wanted overrides is much, much easier."

Comment: @DanielT there is no problem but that doesn't mean i don't want to understand it.